# OpenCV findContour : no matching function

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am trying to use Hough lines in a particular scenario and keep getting no matching function error for findContours method

code

```
...
Mat bw, hsvdst;
...
bw = Mat::zeros(hsvdst.rows, hsvdst.cols, CV_8UC1);
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(bw.clone(), contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘findContours(cv::Mat, st
d::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int> > >&, std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 4> >&, cv::<anonymous enum>, cv::<anonymous enum>)

note: candidates are:
void cv::findContours(cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArrayOfArr
ays, cv::OutputArray, int, int, cv::Point)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘cv::Inpu
tOutputArray {aka const cv::_OutputArray&}’
```

Kindly assist, I am not sure what I am missing here.

Environment: OpenCV 2.4.6.1; Eclipse CDT, Ubuntu 12.04.2

Comment: Compiler is very decent in telling you what the exact problem is. `note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘cv::Inpu
tOutputArray {aka const cv::_OutputArray&}’`

Comment: My Thought was OutputArray maps to Mat type. DO i need an explicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

I got through by replacing

```
findContours(bw.clone(), contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

with

```
Mat m = bw.clone(); findContours(m, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

It's a bit weird though, given that the [definition](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29) of findContour has first argument to be of type InputOutputArray which maps to type Map, and the clone method also return type Mat.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that `Mat::clone()` returns a temporary and you can't get a reference to a temporary. The constructor for `_OutputArray` takes a `Mat&`. Assigning it to a variable first will work (as you show in your answer).